# How do I use jQuery Ajax from inside a Chrome web app

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a web app (extension) with the following manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Porpington",
    "version": "0.0.1.1",
    "app": {
        "launch": {
            "local_path": "main.html"
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "128": "mimsy.jpg"
    },
    "permissions":[
        "http://*/*",
        "tabs"
    ]   
}
```

and I have a very simple main.html (I use jquery 1.6.4)

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<body>
      <a href="javascript:getData()">getData</a><br/>
</body>
<script>
function getData(){
    $.ajax({type: 'get',
          mode: 'abort',
          dataType: 'json',
          url: 'http://localhost/confmart',
          data: {},
          success: function(res){
              alert(res);
          }
    });
    alert(3);
}
</script>
```

I see in the console the request goes out, I see the correct response (in the console)m but for some reason it looks like the `success` event handler is not fired.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you can make an AJAX request from `main.html`. Check if you have to make it through `background page`.

Comment: it is an app, not an extension per-se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `url:` looks suspicious to me.  Add an error handler to your request and a timeout:

```
timeout: 10000,
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
  alert("ERROR: " + textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
}
```

This may or may not be relevant, but there is no `mode:` listed in [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).